How do I expose a library to the global window in Vitest?
So we are in the middle of adding Vitest to an existing project that currently relies on Webpack for bundling our code. We are in the process of rewriting older jQuery code into React.
Right now i'm running into problems because our current project is set up in a way where Node Module libraries like 'polyglot' and 'jQuery' are exposed globally to the entire application window. (IE window.polyglot or window.jQuery). This was pretty easy to set up in Webpack using the expose-loader plugin.
I'm pretty new to Vite and Vitest and have been pouring over the docs to try and understand the best way to accomplish this.
When trying to render one of our React components called <Footer /> in a test that uses a global library called Polyglot for language translation stuff I see this error.
    ReferenceError: Polyglot is not defined
 ❯  src/webhfs/i18n.js:269:18
    267| const _XLATE_PHRASES = Object.freeze(/*<XLATE_PHRASES>*/ {});
    268| 
    269| const polyglot = new Polyglot({
       |                  ^
    270|     phrases: _XLATE_PHRASES,


The library it is complaining about comes from node_modles/node_polyglot and I pull it into our application in Webpack like so.
{
   test: require.resolve("node-polyglot"),
   loader: "expose-loader",
   options: {
      exposes: ["Polyglot"]
   },
},

So I'm trying to replicate how to do this in Vitest.
From reading the docs I thought it had something todo with creating an alias like so.
export default defineConfig({

    define: {
        Polyglot: true
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "Polyglot": './node_modules/node-polyglot',
        }
    },

    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: "jsdom",
        setupFiles: "./test.setup.ts",
        css:true,
    }    
})

But this didn't work as expected either, it just gives me a new and different error.
TypeError: Polyglot is not a constructor

So I'm looking for some direction on where to start with this. What am I not understanding about vitest and globals in the window such as this.
Thanks so much in advance.

Not sure if I understand you correctly. You want to use this lib without actually importing it?

Yes, basically the application was writing a while ago and they pulled everything in as a module to the index page via a script tag. So most of the code is expecting this library to be a variable the global window. Much like how jQuery works. I'm just trying to figure how to tell vitest this.

Okay and if you serve the app using vite - you still simply append it to the window object or how does it work in dev mode?

Ah, okay this might be part of the issue we are using Webpack and Webpack Dev Server. But I'm not sure what you mean. How would you pin it to the window as you suggest, the vitest way.

I think if I would need to define a global - I would to place into the globalThis.

So you are trying to migrate only to vitetest without using vite for your dev env? I am unsure why you would want to attempt that honestly. To me this seems a little unatrual.

I also guess this could be a possible solution for you https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-auto-import

Okay, i guess that's something I can try out. Like I said, I'm new to Vite and Vitest. And I can see from searching on Vitest is the way to go for testing frameworks, but this app on working on is a messy bunch of legacy stuff. What does alias actually do in Vitest. I was also confused on that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Showcasefloyd, if my answer worked. It would be nice you could acept it.

Option 1
I think to achive this the simplest way might to use setupFiles.
Therefore, see this old post.
Option 2
As an alternative you could consider to write your own plugin:

import { resolve } from "path";

export default function globalExposePlugin() {
  return {
    name: "vite-plugin-global-expose",
    enforce: "post",
    transformIndexHtml(html) {
      return html.replace(
        "</head>",
        `<script type="module">
import Polyglot from '${resolve("node_modules/node-polyglot/index.js")}';
window.Polyglot = Polyglot;
</script></head>`
      );
    },
  };
}

Basically this would enable you to inject scripts into your html.
I personally would try option 1

Oh, cool, I could give this a try i suppose. Thanks.
